# React State wasn't changed after I clicked a switch to send a current state to server

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Would you please explain this to me why it's sending `relay1` state with false? Why `handleControlRelay1`  doesn't change the state
I'm doing it wrong by putting this inside a function? `setRelay1((prevValue) => !prevValue);`

```js
// ...

  const [relaysData, setRelaysData] = useState([]);
  console.log(" ~ file: Home.page.js:11 ~ HomePage ~ relaysData", relaysData);
  const [relay1, setRelay1] = useState(null);
  console.log(" ~ file: Home.page.js:12 ~ HomePage ~ relay1", relay1);

  const handleControlRelay1 = () => {
   console.log("before setRelay1", relay1);
   setRelay1((prevValue) => !prevValue);
   console.log("after setRelay1", relay1);
    axios
      .put(`http://localhost:4000/relays/1`, {
        id: 2,
        name: "Superman",
        state_1: relay1,
        state_2: false,
        state_3: false,
        type: "switch-1",
      })
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response.data.message);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error.message);
      });
  };

 useEffect(() => {
    fetchRelaysData();
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!!relaysData) {
      let { state_1 } = relaysData;
      setRelay1(state_1);
    }
  }, [relaysData]);

return (
   <FormControlLabel
              control={
                <Switch
                  checked={!!relay1}
                  onChange={handleControlRelay1}
                />
              }
              label="Zarówka 1"
            />
       )
```

[image]

Comment: setState is asynchronous, by the time the `console.log` runs, the update would not be complete

Comment: So I got to do another function with setRelay1 alone? How would you do this?

Comment: The state value won't be changed immediately after calling setState in the function definition.

Comment: so what is the solution to set this state synchronously or there is a way to this is async with setTimeout()?

Comment: check the answer, should work for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `console.log` will not work as expected because `setstate` is asynchronous.

This will send the right value to the backend:

```js
const handleControlRelay1 = () => {
  console.log("before setRelay1", relay1); 
  const newRelayValue = !relay1
  setRelay1(newRelayValue);
  console.log("after setRelay1", relay1);
  axios
    .put(`http://localhost:4000/relays/1`, {
      id: 2,
      name: "Superman",
      state_1: newRelayValue,
      state_2: false,
      state_3: false,
      type: "switch-1",
    })
    .then((response) => {
      console.log(response.data.message);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error.message);
    });
};
```

Comment: I enter the page I download the data and set value relay1 from state_1 and then when I click on a switch it change the value of relay1 to true but the value of relay1 inside axios.put is still false and when I refresh a page after the first clicking, switch is still on false position

Comment: okay, when you refresh the page it clears the state. Thats the normal behavior

Comment: my bad i haven't changed sending value of state_1 to newRelayValue. Now it works. Thank you. For clarification: const newRelayValue = !relay1 is sync and that's why it works? or why it works that way?

Comment: okay, nice. Please accept the answer

Comment: `useState` is async and `newRelayValue = !relay1` sync and that's why it works? what is behind this code that it works the way it should?

Comment: `newRelayvalue` is what we want the state to be after being set,  but since it's asynchronous, we make it into a variable, and assign the same value to both the state and axios. `newRelayValue = !relay` is synchronous, so it will have the right value